# How to enable or disable a field on value change of another field?

Tags: readonly, orbeon, xforms

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">

<xhtml:head>
  <xhtml:title>Orbeon XForms Sample Form</xhtml:title>

  <xforms:model>
     <xforms:instance id="myModel" xmlns="">
    <form>
            <type>

                <radio></radio>
            </type>
            <type>

                <radio></radio>
            </type>
            <type>

                <radio></radio>
            </type>
    </form>
     </xforms:instance>



     <xforms:bind id="radio" nodeset="instance('myModel')/type/radio"/>


  </xforms:model>
</xhtml:head>

<xhtml:body>

    <table>
        <tr>

        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <table>

            <xforms:repeat nodeset="instance('myModel')/type">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xforms:output ref="position()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td/>
                    <td>
                        <xforms:select1 ref="radio" incremental="true" appearance="minimal">
                            <xforms:item>
                                <xforms:label>Please Select</xforms:label>
                                <xforms:value></xforms:value>
                            </xforms:item><xforms:item>
                                <xforms:label>Yes</xforms:label>
                                <xforms:value>Yes</xforms:value>
                            </xforms:item>
                            <xforms:item>
                                <xforms:label>No</xforms:label>
                                <xforms:value>No</xforms:value>
                            </xforms:item>
                            <xforms:alert>Required</xforms:alert>
                        </xforms:select1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xforms:repeat>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</xhtml:body>

</xhtml:html>
```

In the above form, I want to enable the field based on the value selected on the previous field. For example, if I select **Yes** in the first dropdown, only then the second dropdown should be enabled. If I select **Yes** in the second dropdown, only then the third dropdown should be enabled and so on. How can I implement this ? Can I do something in the xforms-value-changed event ? Or can I implement this in xforms:bind ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, you can do this with an `xforms:bind`. The following will do the job in your example:

```
<xforms:bind id="radio" nodeset="instance('myModel')/type/radio"
    relevant="empty(../preceding-sibling::type)
              or ../preceding-sibling::type[1]/radio = 'Yes'"/>
```

The most subtle part here is the use of the [preceding axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#axes) to get the `type` element that comes just before the current one.

Comment: Yes, it is working exactly how I wanted.. Thank u so much.. :)